# How can I prove $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{4}n^2$ for all whole numbers $n \geq 3$?

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, induction

$\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{4}n^2 ; n \geq 3$

Induction first step:

$n=3$

$\sqrt{3}<\frac{9}{4}$ which is true

Induction second step:

$n=k$

$\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{k}<\frac{1}{4}k^2$

Induction third step:

$n=k+1$

$\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}<\frac{1}{4}(k+1)^2$

From the assumption in the second step we know that: $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{k}<\frac{1}{4}k^2$

From this we can assume that: $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}<\frac{1}{4}k^2+\sqrt{k+1}$

So we know that $\frac{1}{4}k^2+\sqrt{k+1}$ is bigger than $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$. We can then replace $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}$ in the statement that we want to prove with $\frac{1}{4}k^2+\sqrt{k+1}$

So:

$$\frac{1}{4}k^2+\sqrt{k+1}<\frac{1}{4}(k+1)^2$$

$$16k+16<4k^2+4k+1$$

$$0<4k^2-12k-15$$

When I solve this I get $\left( \frac{3+2\sqrt{6}}{2};+\infty \right)$ for positive numbers

--Edit--

$3\not\in\left( \frac{3+2\sqrt{6}}{2};+\infty \right)$, but we manually proved above that the statement is true for $3$.

In this case, we proved by induction that this statement is true for $n \geq 4$. We don't need to rewrite our proof but only include a new first induction step.

*Induction first step:

$n=4$

$\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}<\frac{16}{4}$ which is true

And because we manually proved for $3$ we can say that this statement is true for all whole numbers $n \geq 3$

Is this correct?

--

Thanks

Comment: Start with initial step $k\ge 4$ and you should be fine, i.e., prove the statement for $k=4$... The title statement is correct if the case for $k=3$ is proved separately from the induction.

Comment: $4$ is in $\left( \frac{3+2\sqrt{6}}{2};+\infty \right)$, so it should be alright. What I don't get is that I proved manually that this statement works for $3$... I don't get it

Comment: i’m pretty sure $3$ is in that interval. One half plus root six is less than three, which follows since $6•4<25$

Comment: $\frac{3+2\sqrt{6}}{2}$ is approximately 3.94949

Comment: @GeTo ah, my fault. i read 3/2 as 1/2 on accident

Comment: Ah, I see. But I still don't get why it doesn't fit into that interval but still works on $3$

Comment: Alternatively, $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}<n \sqrt{n} \le \frac{1}{4}n^2$ works for $n\ge 16$. Then check manually for $3\le n<16$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a statement $S(n)$. You attempt to show $S(3)$, and that $S(n)$ implies $S(n+1)$ for all $n \geq 3$. Unfortunately this works only for $n \geq 4$.

You solve the conundrum by showing both $S(3)$ and $S(4)$, and since the induction statement is true for $n \geq 4$, $S(n)$ is also true for all $n \geq 5$.

It happens quite often that the induction statement is only true for $n \geq N$. In that case you prove $S(N)$ by hand and this proves $S(n)$ for all $n \geq N$. Then you try to prove $S(n-1)$, $S(N-2)$ and so on.

But $S(N)$ might also be false. In that case, if you find an $m \geq N$ where $S(m)$ is true, you know $S(n)$ is true for all $n \geq m$, and you try to prove $S(m-1)$ and so on as well. That would happen if you tried to prove $\text{LHS}<\text{RHS}-1000000$. You might not find any such $m$ because the statement is false for all $n$.